# SQL (SQLite) count for null-fields over all columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

I've got a table called `datapoints` with about 150 columns and 2600 rows. I know, 150 columns is too much, but I got this db after importing a csv and it is not possible to shrink the number of columns.

I have to get some statistical stuff out of the data. E.g. one question would be: 
Give me the total number of fields (of all columns), which are null. Does somebody have any idea how I can do this efficiently?

For one column it isn't a problem:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM datapoints tb1 where 'tb1'.'column1' is null;
```

But how can I solve this for all columns together, without doing it by hand for every column?

Best, 
Michael

Comment: Nearly eight years later ... a solution that will handle arbitrarily many columns (for all or for selected tables within an SQLite database) is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887988/how-to-find-which-columns-dont-have-any-data-all-values-are-null in the form of a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Lamak's idea, how about this idea:

```
SELECT (N * COUNT(*)) - (
    COUNT(COLUMN_1) 
  + COUNT(COLUMN_2) 
  + ... 
  + COUNT(COLUMN_N)
)
FROM DATAPOINTS;
```

where `N` is the number of columns. The trick will be in making the summation series of COUNT(column), but that shouldn't be too terrible with a good text editor and/or spreadsheet.

Comment: The above has been tried in DB2 and Access, so hopefully this may work in sqlite too.

Comment: The suggestion to use a spreadsheet to help create the query is a good one. The only thing not great about the query itself is N has to be computed and kept up to date manually. Given Murphy's law that might not be ideal.

Comment: This works for my problem, thanks.
In SQLite, the syntax should be like the following:
SELECT (N * COUNT(*)) - (
    COUNT(t1.'COLUMN_1') 
  + COUNT(t1.'COLUMN_2') 
  + ... 
  + COUNT(t1.'COLUMN_N')
) FROM datapoints t1;

Answer (score 0):

Well, `COUNT` (and most aggregations funcions) ignore `NULL` values. In your case, since you are using `COUNT(*)`, it counts every row in the table, but you can do that on any column. Something like this:

```
SELECT TotalRows-Column1NotNullCount, etc
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(1) TotalRows,
           COUNT(column1) Column1NotNullCount,
           COUNT(column2) Column2NotNullCount,
           COUNT(column3) Column3NotNullCount ....
    FROM datapoints) A
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is an easy way to do it. i'd get started on the 150 queries. you only have to replace one word (column name) each time.

Answer (score 0):

To get started it's often helpful to use a visual query tool to generate a field list and then use cut/paste/search/replace or manipulation in a spreadsheet program to transform it into what is needed. To do it all in one step you can use something like:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE COLUMN1 WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
       SUM(CASE COLUMN2 WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
       SUM(CASE COLUMN3 WHEN NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
       ...
FROM DATAPOINTS;
```

With a visual query builder you can quickly generate:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3  ... FROM DATAPOINTS;
```

You can then replace the comma with all the text that needs to appear between two field names followed by fixing up the first and last fields. So in the example search for "," and replace with " WHEN NULL 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE " and then fix up the first and last fields.