# Return columns in a table that have null values for every entry

Tags: sql, select, null

I have a bunch of columns and I want only the ones that have all null values. I want to do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE COUNT(*) = 0
```

^but this doesn't do what I want it to do. Can anybody guide me in the right direction for this?

EDIT: For clarity, I have n columns c1, through cn, each have some data type that doesn't matter, and each column allows for nulls.

I want to run a query that returns columns C1 through Cm (m <= n) where for 1 <= i <= m, count(Ci) = 0.

I get the following error when I run the above query:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Anything else you need me to clarify?

Comment: You'll have to better explain what your data are and what is the expected query result. As it is, it's unclear what you want.

Comment: You will need to do some thing like this -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887988/how-to-find-which-columns-dont-have-any-data-all-values-are-null

Comment: A SQL Query returns a fixed set of columns.  If you want a variable number of columns, you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? 

[sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291/sql-select-columns-with-null-values-only