# Select non-empty columns using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I am using SQL Server 2012. i have a table with 90 columns. I am trying to select only columns that contains data. After searching i used the following procedure:

1- Getting all columns count using one select query

2- Pivoting Result Table into a Temp table

3- Creating Select query

4- Executing this query

Here is the query i used:

```
DECLARE @strTablename  varchar(100) = 'dbo.MyTable'
DECLARE @strQuery  varchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @strSecondQuery  varchar(max) = 'SELECT '
DECLARE @strUnPivot as varchar(max) = ' UNPIVOT ([Count] for [Column] IN ('

CREATE TABLE ##tblTemp([Column] varchar(50), [Count]  Int)

SELECT @strQuery = ISNULL(@strQuery,'') + 'Count([' + name + ']) as [' + name + ']  ,' from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(@strTablename) and is_nullable = 1
SELECT @strUnPivot = ISNULL(@strUnPivot,'') + '[' + name + '] ,' from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(@strTablename) and is_nullable = 1


SET @strQuery = 'SELECT [Column],[Count] FROM ( SELECT ' + SUBSTRING(@strQuery,1,LEN(@strQuery) - 1) + ' FROM ' + @strTablename + ') AS p ' + SUBSTRING(@strUnPivot,1,LEN(@strUnPivot) - 1) + ')) AS unpvt '

INSERT INTO ##tblTemp EXEC (@strQuery)

SELECT @strSecondQuery = @strSecondQuery + '[' + [Column] + '],'  from ##tblTemp WHERE [Count] > 0

DROP TABLE ##tblTemp

SET @strSecondQuery = SUBSTRING(@strSecondQuery,1,LEN(@strSecondQuery) - 1) + ' FROM ' + @strTablename

EXEC (@strSecondQuery)
```

The problem is that this query is TOO SLOW. Is there a best way to achieve this?

**Notes:**

- Table have only one clustered index on primary key Column `ID` and does not contains any other indexes.
- Table is not editable.
- Table contains very large data.
- Query is taking about 1 minute to be executed

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887988/how-to-find-which-columns-dont-have-any-data-all-values-are-null This has several code samples that may help.

Comment: @MisterPositive thanks for your help. It was the topic i started my work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know if this is faster, but you might use one trick: `FOR XML AUTO` will ommit columns without content:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col1 INT,col2 INT,col3 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (1,2,NULL),(1,NULL,NULL),(NULL,NULL,NULL);

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl AS tbl
FOR XML AUTO
```

This is the result: `col3` is missing...

```
<tbl col1="1" col2="2" />
<tbl col1="1" />
<tbl />
```

Knowing this, you could find the list of columns, which are not NULL in all rows, like this:

```
DECLARE @ColList VARCHAR(MAX)=
STUFF
(
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Attr.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)')
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM @tbl AS tbl
            FOR XML AUTO,TYPE
        ) AS TheXML
    ) AS t
    CROSS APPLY t.TheXML.nodes('/tbl/@*') AS A(Attr) 
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''
);

SELECT @ColList
```

The content of `@ColList` is now `col1,col2`. This string you can place in a dynamically created `SELECT`.

### UPDATE: Hints

It would be very clever, to replace the `SELECT *` with a column list created from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` excluding all *not-nullable*. And - if needed and possible - types, wich contain very large data (BLOBs).

### UPDATE2: Performance

Don't know what your *very large data* means actually... Just tried this on a table with about 500.000 rows (with `SELECT *`) and it returned correctly after less than one minute. Hope, this is fast enough...

Comment: Solid example / demonstration  +1

Comment: @Shnugo my query is taking about 1 minute and yours is taking about 5 minute!!

Comment: I accepted this answer because it learned me a new way to achieve this even if it doesn't improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

Try using this condition:

```
where @columnname IS NOT NULL AND @columnname <> ' '
```

Comment: This will return the rows where the selected column is not empty. It is not related to the question!!