# Getting column data length against column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[Output of Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh55D.png) I am trying to get column names and column data length for columns and further eliminate the columns with 0 data length values in it.I am new to SQL server and after lot of searching I found a query which would give me solution for my problem which is as follows :-

```
    DECLARE @strTablename  varchar(100) = 'dbo.test'
    DECLARE @strQuery  varchar(max) = ''
    DECLARE @strSecondQuery  varchar(max) = 'SELECT '
    DECLARE @strUnPivot as varchar(max) = ' UNPIVOT ([Count] for [Column] IN ('


    SELECT @strQuery = ISNULL(@strQuery,'') + 'datalength([' + name + ']) as [' + name + ']  ,' from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(@strTablename) and is_nullable = 1
    SELECT @strUnPivot = ISNULL(@strUnPivot,'') + '[' + name + '] ,' from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(@strTablename) and is_nullable = 1


    SET @strQuery = 'SELECT  [Column],[Count] FROM ( SELECT ' + SUBSTRING(@strQuery,1,LEN(@strQuery) - 1) + ' FROM ' + @strTablename + ') AS p ' + SUBSTRING(@strUnPivot,1,LEN(@strUnPivot) - 1) + ')) AS unpvt '


    EXEC (@strQuery

)
```

But after using this query I am getting duplicate column names and count. Can anybody explain me this query so that I can change it the way I want especially I am not able to understand @strQuery and @strUnpivot.I used the code given in the following link to fit my requirements [Select non-empty columns using SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895126/select-non-empty-columns-using-sql-server). Thanks!

Comment: What are you getting, and what are you trying to get instead?   Give examples in addition to descriptions.

Comment: I am getting duplicate column name against its data lengths

Comment: If I use count instead of data length in @strQuery the output is correct...but with data length i get repetitive column names.so I am sure I am messing up with the usage of datalength.

Comment: Also for one column I am getting two different data lengths..I have attached the output wherein eventinfo column has 119 and 132 as data length

Comment: The best way to debug these kinds of things it is print/select the dynamic query. If you do that you would discover that your subquery is not quite right. Pretty sure you want MAX around datalength so it gets the longest value for each column instead of each value.

Comment: Thank you so much.It worked for me. Can you please explain me the working of those two statements @strQuery and @strUnpivot?Thanks!

Comment: I am new to SQL server but i will try to debug the query.Thanks again!

Comment: I am a bit scared that you need me to explain your code to you. ;) strQuery is the dynamic sql string you are creating. strUnpivot is the dynamic UNPIVOT you are creating.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895126/select-non-empty-columns-using-sql-server I used the code given in this link and further after looking at it I realised all i need to do is to change count to datalength which i think for a user with 1 day of sql server experience was good enough :)

Comment: Add Select @strQuery before the last line and you can see the sql that is generated. That will help explain what is happening.

Comment: Thanks Sean for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Right now your code is creating and executing this statement:

```
SELECT  [Column],[Count] 
FROM 
( 
  SELECT 
    datalength([ParentID]) as [ParentID]  ,
    datalength([Content]) as [Content], 
    datalength([Intermediate]) as [Intermediate]  ,
    datalength([SnapshotDataID]) as [SnapshotDataID]  ,
    datalength([LinkSourceID]) as [LinkSourceID],
    datalength([Property]) as [Property],
    datalength([Description]) as [Description],
    datalength([Hidden]) as [Hidden],
    datalength([MimeType]) as [MimeType],
    datalength([SnapshotLimit]) as [SnapshotLimit],
    datalength([Parameter]) as [Parameter],
    datalength([ExecutionTime]) as [ExecutionTime],
    datalength([SubType]) as [SubType],
    datalength([ComponentID]) as [ComponentID]   
  FROM **<YOUR TABLE>**
) AS p  
UNPIVOT 
(
  [Count] for [Column] IN 
  (
    [ParentID] ,[Content] ,[Intermediate] ,[SnapshotDataID] ,[LinkSourceID] ,[Property] ,[Description] ,
    [Hidden] ,[MimeType] ,[SnapshotLimit] ,[Parameter] ,[ExecutionTime] ,[SubType] ,[ComponentID] 
  )
) AS unpvt
```

What I think you are looking for is a Dynamic SQL statement that creates this:

```
SELECT [column], [count] = MAX([count])
FROM
(
  SELECT  [Column],[Count] 
  FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT 
      datalength([ParentID]) as [ParentID]  ,
      datalength([Content]) as [Content], 
      datalength([Intermediate]) as [Intermediate]  ,
      datalength([SnapshotDataID]) as [SnapshotDataID]  ,
      datalength([LinkSourceID]) as [LinkSourceID],
      datalength([Property]) as [Property],
      datalength([Description]) as [Description],
      datalength([Hidden]) as [Hidden],
      datalength([MimeType]) as [MimeType],
      datalength([SnapshotLimit]) as [SnapshotLimit],
      datalength([Parameter]) as [Parameter],
      datalength([ExecutionTime]) as [ExecutionTime],
      datalength([SubType]) as [SubType],
      datalength([ComponentID]) as [ComponentID]   
    FROM **<YOUR TABLE>**
  ) AS p
  UNPIVOT 
  (
    [Count] for [Column] IN 
    (
      [ParentID] ,[Content] ,[Intermediate] ,[SnapshotDataID] ,[LinkSourceID] ,[Property] ,[Description] ,
    [Hidden] ,[MimeType] ,[SnapshotLimit] ,[Parameter] ,[ExecutionTime] ,[SubType] ,[ComponentID] 
    )
  ) AS unpvt 
) x
GROUP BY [column]
```

To dynamically create this statement you would do this:

```
DECLARE @strTablename  varchar(100) = <YOUR TABLE>
   DECLARE @strQuery  varchar(max) = ''
   DECLARE @strSecondQuery  varchar(max) = 'SELECT '
   DECLARE @strUnPivot as varchar(max) = ' UNPIVOT ([Count] for [Column] IN ('

   SELECT @strQuery = ISNULL(@strQuery,'') + 'datalength([' + name + ']) as [' + name + ']  ,' 
   FROM sys.columns 
   WHERE object_id = object_id(@strTablename) and is_nullable = 1;

   SELECT @strUnPivot = ISNULL(@strUnPivot,'') + '[' + name + '] ,' 
   from sys.columns 
   where object_id = object_id(@strTablename) and is_nullable = 1;
   SET @strQuery = 'SELECT [Column],[Count] FROM ( SELECT ' + 
     SUBSTRING(@strQuery,1,LEN(@strQuery) - 1) + ' FROM ' + @strTablename + ') AS p ' +
     SUBSTRING(@strUnPivot,1,LEN(@strUnPivot) - 1) + ')) AS unpvt '


   SET @strQuery = 
   'SELECT [column], [count] = MAX([count]) FROM (' + @strQuery +
   ') x GROUP BY [column]'

--PRINT @strQuery;
   EXEC (@strQuery);
```

One way I troubleshoot this is is using a PRINT statement to see what my Dynamic SQL is creating. To better understand what's going on here I would suggest learning more about the T-SQL UNPIVOT statement as well as Dynamic SQL.