# Select column only with values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a table in database structured as below.

```
col1  col2  col3  col4 col5  col6  frnkeyid1  frnkeyid2
-----------------------------------------------------------
  a     2    3                         2          4
  b     1    4                         2          5 
  c     12   5                         2          6
```

In the above table, no data is inserted in `col4`, `col5` and `col6`.
Now I want to write a procedure/query which removes all columns from the result table where no value is entered for that column.

F.e. the result for the above table:

```
col1  col2  col3 frnkeyid1  frnkeyid2
-----------------------------------------
  a     2    3      2          4
  b     1    4      2          5 
  c     12   5      2          6
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: I removed all those dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used here.

Comment: sql server 2008

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895126/select-non-empty-columns-using-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
-- For obtain used columns
DECLARE @ColNames NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
SELECT  @ColNames = @ColNames + ', ' + QUOTENAME(ColNames) 
FROM MyTable UNPIVOT( V FOR ColNames IN ([col1],[col2],[col3],[col4],[col5],[col6],[frnkeyid1],[frnkeyid2])) UNPVT
GROUP BY QUOTENAME(ColNames)


DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ' + STUFF(@ColNames,1,1,'') + ' FROM MyTable'

EXEC (@query)
```

Result:

```
col1        col2        col3        frnkeyid1   frnkeyid2
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           3           2           4
2           1           4           2           5
3           12          5           2           6
```

Answer (score 1):

**This solution literally removes all columns from the result table**

You need to use dynamic SQL. Let me show example.

I guess, `no data` means `NULL`.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (
    col1  char(1),
    col2  int,
    col3  int,
    col4  int,
    col5  int,
    col6  int,
    frnkeyid1 int,  
    frnkeyid2 int
)

INSERT INTO dbo.test  VALUES
('a', 2,  3, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 4),
('b', 1,  4, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 5),
('c', 12, 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, 2, 6)
```

That is a declaration of test table. To build a query and execute it use this code:

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname = N'test',
        @SQLQuery nvarchar(max) = N''

SELECT @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + N'
IF (
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT '+ QUOTENAME(c.[name]) +') = 0 AND MAX(' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) +') IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[Name]) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.[Name]) + ') = 1
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(s.[Name]) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '
    DROP COLUMN '+ QUOTENAME(c.[name]) +'

    PRINT ''Column name '+ QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + ' was droped from table ' + QUOTENAME(s.[Name]) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '''
END;'
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
    ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
    On t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE t.[name] = @TableName

PRINT @SQLQuery
--EXEC (@SQLQuery)
```

PRINT statement will give you this

```
IF (
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT [col1]) = 0 AND MAX([col1]) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM [dbo].[test]) = 1
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test]
    DROP COLUMN [col1]

    PRINT 'Column name [col1] was droped from table [dbo].[test]'
END;
```

For each column.

So, if there are no values column will be droped. You can delete

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[test]
DROP COLUMN [col1]
```

And run script to see, what columns will be droped from table.

If you run this script on test table and then make:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test
```

That will bring you:

```
col1    col2    col3    frnkeyid1   frnkeyid2
a       2       3       2           4
b       1       4       2           5
c       12      5       2           6
```